# Export react app to static and separate html files, for use in django

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a Github repo (https://github.com/cupliz/medical-calculators) with some components (calculators) that I want to integrate into my Django app, without having to do a SPA; I want to take advantage of Django's templating system. Integrating the React app as a Django app did not succeed (I tried a dozen tutorials based on Webpack and babel). I figured out the easiest way may be exporting the react app to static HTML files. I have tried the following:

- `npm run build` command (but this didn't work presumably because of the routing).
- **react-snap** module
- **react-snapshot** module
- **react-static** module (this requires the app to be built with react static from the start).

What is the easiest way to export an existing react app, with routing, to static HTML files that can be served without any node.js on the hosting server?